# Vagrant shared folders wipes all the contents in my folders

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vagrant

In VagrantFile configuration file: `config.vm.synced_folder "../nginx_config/", "/etc/nginx"`

Once I add it my configuration file and reload vagrant instance, it gets the directory on guest empty I tried different possibilities to change the location of the folder `nginx_config` on host (my computer) but I always get the same result.

When I disable sharing, the contents of `/etc/nginx` on guest (vagrant)is back again.

What can be the problem here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Vagrant's synced folders mechanism, it actually use VirtualBox's Shared Folders feature. (I assume here you use VirtualBox as provider)

Shared Folders is implemented by mounting your folder in the location you specified in similar manner as it's being done with a network shares.

In Linux if you use a mount point with existing files in it, the original files will become invisible after the mount, and reappear after unmount. See [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/200685/what-does-linux-do-with-existing-files-in-a-mount-point).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I mean the folder inside vagrant not the folder on my machine (mount point), when I share it to be visible on my local/host machine, it gets empty, when I stop the sharing, it is back again with all the files and folders that it had before

Comment: I think you confuse the concept how synced folders work. When you use shared folders, you share what's on host machine (what you call 'my machine') with guest virtual machine (what you call 'vagrant'). So the mount point is inside the virtual machine, not the host.

Comment: probably you are right, Thanks for your quick responses again :))

Comment: I thought it the other way around!!